# Dialogflow v2 Beta 1 Update Intent with Python

Tags: dialogflow-es, grpc, google-api-python-client

I am lost.
I have a currently existing Intent in my project, and I am trying to update ALL fields programmatically because that is what my project requires.

I read [this](https://dialogflow-python-client-v2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gapic/v2beta1/api.html) documentation and checked [this source file](https://github.com/googleapis/dialogflow-python-client-v2/blob/master/dialogflow_v2beta1/gapic/intents_client.py) on GitHub, and I think the reason I am getting an error is because I don't understand this part of the source:

> Args:
>               intent (Union[dict, ~google.cloud.dialogflow_v2beta1.types.Intent]): Required. The intent
>   to update.
>                   Format: `projects/<Project ID>/agent/intents/<Intent ID>`.
>                   If a dict is provided, it must be of the same form as the protobuf
>                   message :class:`~google.cloud.dialogflow_v2beta1.types.Intent`

**(Line 484 for reference)**

The platform works great I just don't know what I am missing here..

**My code**

```
from constants import *
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import dialogflow_v2beta1
cred = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(AUTH_JSON)
client = dialogflow_v2beta1.IntentsClient(credentials=cred)
params = dialogflow_v2beta1.types.Intent.Parameter(name='test', display_name='test', value='test', is_list=True)
t = dialogflow_v2beta1.types.Intent.Message.Text(text='TEST TEXT')
m = dialogflow_v2beta1.types.Intent.Message(text=t)
p = dialogflow_v2beta1.types.Intent.TrainingPhrase.Part(text='test',entity_type='@test_type', alias='test_alias', user_defined=True)
t = dialogflow_v2beta1.types.Intent.TrainingPhrase(name='test',type=2, parts=[p])
modified_intent = dialogflow_v2beta1.types.Intent(
    display_name='test',       
    messages=[m],
    webhook_state=1,
    is_fallback=False,
    ml_disabled=False,
    input_context_names=PROJECT_DIR+'agent/sessions/-/contexts/' + 'TEST_CONTEXT',
    events='TESTING EVENT',
    training_phrases=[t],
    action='TESTING ACTION',
    reset_contexts=False,
    parameters=[params]
    ) 
name = client.intent_path(PROJECT_NAME, '7b8f2105-53d4-4724-8d4c-0170b8db7028')
intent = client.get_intent(name)
client.update_intent(intent=modified_intent, language_code=LANGUAGE_CODE, intent_view=0)
```

**Full error message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/envs/data/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/envs/data/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 550, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/anaconda/envs/data/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 467, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
        details = "Resource name '' does not match 'projects/*/agent/intents/*'."
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1552461629.958860000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1036,"grpc_message":"Resource name '' does not match 'projects/*/agent/intents/*'.","grpc_status":3}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    client.update_intent(intent=modified_intent, language_code=LANGUAGE_CODE, intent_view=0)
  File "/anaconda/envs/data/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dialogflow_v2beta1/gapic/intents_client.py", line 535, in update_intent
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata)
  File "/anaconda/envs/data/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 143, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/envs/data/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 270, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/anaconda/envs/data/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 179, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/anaconda/envs/data/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 214, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/envs/data/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Resource name '' does not match 'projects/*/agent/intents/*'.
```

Comment: what is value of **PROJECT_NAME** ?

Comment: My basic project name that is given when I go to the settings page in my agent. Essentially it is only the "project ID".

Comment: the correct format for the intent name is : `'projects/{{project_id}}/agent/intents/{{your_intent_id}}'`

Comment: @sid8491 fetching the intent and assigning it to the variable 'name' works fine in my debug, the error happens when the code executes `client.update_intent(intent=modified_intent, language_code=LANGUAGE_CODE, intent_view=0)`

Comment: ok i was able to reproduce it and i got the problem here, you need to make modifications in the intent which you are getting, then assigning that to the `update_intent`. will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to get the intent which you want to modify correctly by using

```
name = client.intent_path(PROJECT_NAME, your_intent_id)
```

You will get complete definition of your intent.
Then you need to change the values of this intent by accessing them and assigning your values.
After that, you need to pass the same intent in your `update_intent()` function.
It is also advised to use `update_mask` to avoid changing any other field or setting rest of the fields None.

Here is an example of updating intent display_name from **greet** to **hello**:

```
client = dialogflow.IntentsClient()
intent_name = client.intent_path(project_id, intent_id)
intent = client.get_intent(intent_name, intent_view=dialogflow.enums.IntentView.INTENT_VIEW_FULL)
intent.display_name = 'hello'
update_mask = field_mask_pb2.FieldMask(paths=['display_name']) 
print(response)
```

You will need ope extra import as well in your code:

```
from google.protobuf import field_mask_pb2
```

This way, intent's display_name will be changed.
You can do same for the rest of your properties as well. Just remember to pass the value which the property is expecting by following [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.intents) and you can take help from [this issue](https://github.com/googleapis/dialogflow-python-client-v2/issues/68) as well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Dude! You are a rockstar, thank you so much. 
On the line `update_mask = field_mask_pb2.FieldMask(paths=['display_name']` please add a ')' at the end, SO will not let me do this due to a character minimum length limit.
Cheers man

Comment: @Jonathan oh yes, sorry missed it by mistake. fixed now.

Comment: @Jonathan sure, let me know how can i contact you, :)

Comment: I just followed your Medium channel, do you have a LinkedIn profile?

Comment: @Jonathan i followed you back on medium .... linkedin : https://www.linkedin.com/in/sid8491